# "Fastboot devices" command doesn't work after macos high sierra 10.14.4 upgrade

Tags: fastboot, macos

I recently upgraded my 2016 MacBook Pro to High Sierra 10.4.4 update and since the update "fastboot devices" command hasn't been working. "fastboot" itself gives a response but "fastboot devices" command gives 
`ERROR: Couldn't create a device interface iterator: (e00002bd)
ERROR: Couldn't create a device interface iterator: (e00002bd)` error. It comes twice on the window.

Comment: this worked for me!!
https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/
cant believe it.

Comment: "fastboot devices" has been working for me for years until I have upgraded to Mac OS 10.14.4.    I think this is a regression of the Mac OS.    I'm waiting for a new OS upgrade that fixes this regression.    In the meantime, I'm not sure if there is any workaround.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to Apple. Following is the link:
https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=50376579

Comment: I have upgraded to Mac OS 10.14.5 and this regression is still not fixed. It's better to find a workaround.

Comment: jonathanzh, have you found a workaround? I'm also on 10.14.5 and haven't had any luck. I have access to a Windows and a Linux PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same error in version 28.0.3 but it's fixed in 29.0.1.
You can download it from the [official site](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools).
It's also available from MacPorts, e.g

```
port install android-platform-tools
```

Comment: Install via brew with this command: brew cask install android-platform-tools

Answer (score 7):

This might be a [regression in android-platform-tools](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64292422). Try fastboot version 9dc0875966c0-android from [android-platform-tools 26.0.1](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.1-darwin.zip) as it works for me on macOS 10.14.4

Comment: I confirm that the fastboot version in android-platform-tools 26.0.1 works on macOS 10.14.4. This is a nice workaround before Apple fixes this regression.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Fastboot problem which has been fixed by google. See the release notes here:
[SDK Platform Tools release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)

Here is what solved my problem:
Start android studio->go to sdk manager->select SDK Platform Tools -> Check "Show Details" -> Select Android Platform Tools -> Upgrade to 29.0.1 or newer.

See the images for more details:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: `brew cask install android-platform-tools`

Long answer:

I was in the same case (on macOS 10.14.6):

```
$ fastboot devices
ERROR: Couldn't create a device interface iterator: (e00002bd)
```

I tried previous answers of this topic without success, so I searched which program is at the origin of `fastboot` command:

```
$ which fastboot
/usr/local/bin/fastboot

$ la -l /usr/local/bin/fastboot
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Klemart3D  admin  52  7 jun  2016 /usr/local/bin/fastboot@ -> ../Cellar/android-platform-tools/23.0.1/bin/fastboot
```

In my case, I found my fastboot command was not managed by Android Studio or an independent tool but is a shortcut of a brew formula. So I forced install of new "android-platform-tools" paquet:

```
$ brew cask install android-platform-tools
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r30.0.0-darwin.zip
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying SHA-256 checksum for Cask 'android-platform-tools'.
==> Installing Cask android-platform-tools
==> Linking Binary 'adb' to '/usr/local/bin/adb'.
==> Linking Binary 'dmtracedump' to '/usr/local/bin/dmtracedump'.
==> Linking Binary 'etc1tool' to '/usr/local/bin/etc1tool'.
==> Linking Binary 'fastboot' to '/usr/local/bin/fastboot'.
==> Linking Binary 'hprof-conv' to '/usr/local/bin/hprof-conv'.
==> Linking Binary 'mke2fs' to '/usr/local/bin/mke2fs'.
  android-platform-tools was successfully installed!
```

Shortcut is updated to last android-platform-tools version folder:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/fastboot
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Klemart3D  admin  73  7 may 17:59 /usr/local/bin/fastboot -> /usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/30.0.0/platform-tools/fastboot
```

And I have no more error!

```
$ fastboot devices
```